# How to find the Filename with the latest version in C#

Tags: c#, regex, file-io, directory

I have a folder that is filled with dwg files so I just need to find the latest version of a File or if a File has no versions then copy it to a directory.  For example here are three files:

> ABBIE 08-10 #6-09H4 FINAL 06-12-2012.dwg
>   ABBIE 08-10 #6-09H4 FINAL 06-12-2012_1.dwg
>   ABBIE 08-10 #6-09H4 FINAL 06-12-2012_2.dwg

Notice the difference is one file has a `_1` and another has a `_2` so the latest file here is the `_2`.  I need to keep the latest file and copy it to a directory.  Some files will not have different versions so those can be copied. I cannot focus on the creation date of the file or the modified date because in many instances they are the same so all I have to go on is the file name itself.  I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do this than what I will post below.

```
DirectoryInfo myDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"H:\Temp\Test");
var Files = myDir.GetFiles("*.dwg");

string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(@"H:\Temp\Test", "*FINAL*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
ArrayList WithUnderscores = new ArrayList();
string nameNOunderscores = "";

for (int i = 0; i < fileList.Length; i++)
{
    //Try to get just the filename..
    string filename = fileList[i].Split('.')[0];
    int position = filename.LastIndexOf('\\');
    filename = filename.Substring(position + 1);
    filename = filename.Split('_')[0];

    foreach (FileInfo allfiles in Files)
    {
        var withoutunderscore = allfiles.Name.Split('_')[0];
        withoutunderscore = withoutunderscore.Split('.')[0];
        if (withoutunderscore.Equals(filename))
        {
            nameNOunderscores = filename;
            list.Add(allfiles.Name);
        }
    }

    //If there is a number after the _ then capture it in an ArrayList
    if (list.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (string nam in list)
        {
            if (nam.Contains("_"))
            {
                //need regex to grab numeric value after _
                var match = new Regex("_(?<number>[0-9]+)").Match(nam);
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    var value = match.Groups["number"].Value;
                    var number = Int32.Parse(value);

                    WithUnderscores.Add(number);
                }
            }
        }

        int removedcount = 0;

        //Whats the max value?
        if (WithUnderscores.Count > 0)
        {
            var maxval = GetMaxValue(WithUnderscores);
            Int32 intmax = Convert.ToInt32(maxval);

            foreach (FileInfo deletefile in Files)
            {
                string shorten = deletefile.Name.Split('.')[0];
                shorten = shorten.Split('_')[0];
                if (shorten == nameNOunderscores && deletefile.Name != nameNOunderscores + "_" + intmax + ".dwg")  
                {
                    //Keep track of count of Files that are no good to us so we can iterate to next set of files
                    removedcount = removedcount + 1;

                }
                else
                {
                    //Copy the "Good" file to a seperate directory
                    File.Copy(@"H:\Temp\Test\" + deletefile.Name, @"H:\Temp\AllFinals\" + deletefile.Name, true); 
                }
            }

            WithUnderscores.Clear();
            list.Clear();
        }

        i = i + removedcount;
    }
    else
    {
        //This File had no versions so it is good to be copied to the "Good" directory
        File.Copy(@"H:\Temp\SH_Plats\" + filename, @"H:\Temp\AllFinals" + filename, true);
        i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: use `methods`, look into `Path.GetFilename()`, `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`, I suggest `lowerCamelCasingForVariables` instead of `everythinginlowercase` - note that `fileList[i].Split('.')[0];` looks suspicious for `NullReference`....

Comment: Do you have any control over the file names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a Regex based solution, and apparently come late to the party in the meantime.

`(?<fileName>[A-Za-z0-9-# ]*)_?(?<version>[0-9]+)?\.dwg`

this regex will recognise the fileName and version and split them into groups, a pretty simple foreach loop to get the most recent files in a dictionary (cos I'm lazy) and then you just need to put the fileNames back together again before you access them.

`var fileName = file.Key + "_" + file.Value + ".dwg"`

**full code**

```
var files = new[] {
    "ABBIE 08-10 #6-09H4 FINAL 06-12-2012.dwg",
    "ABBIE 08-10 #6-09H4 FINAL 06-12-2012_1.dwg",
    "ABBIE 08-10 #6-09H4 FINAL 06-12-2012_2.dwg",
    "Second File.dwg",
    "Second File_1.dwg",
    "Third File.dwg"
};

// regex to split fileName from version
var r = new Regex( @"(?<fileName>[A-Za-z0-9-# ]*)_?(?<version>[0-9]+)?\.dwg" );
var latestFiles = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (var f in files)
{
    var parsedFileName = r.Match( f );
    var fileName = parsedFileName.Groups["fileName"].Value; 
    var version = parsedFileName.Groups["version"].Success ? int.Parse( parsedFileName.Groups["version"].Value ) : 0;

    if( latestFiles.ContainsKey( fileName ) && version > latestFiles[fileName] )
    {
        // replace if this file has a newer version
        latestFiles[fileName] = version;
    }
    else
    {
        // add all newly found filenames
        latestFiles.Add( fileName, version );
    }
}

// open all most recent files
foreach (var file in latestFiles)
{
    var fileToCopy = File.Open( file.Key + "_" + file.Value + ".dwg" );
    // ...
}
```

Comment: this is almost working perfect. What if I have a file like Adam, Terry 09-08 4-14H FINAL 09-09-2012.dwg This program is removing the Adam, and when I attempt to copy it only has Terry 09-08 4-14H FINAL 09-09-2012.dwg which naturally it can't find to copy

Comment: I haven't allowed for comma's in the regex. Try this instead: `new Regex( @"(?<fileName>[A-Za-z0-9-#, ]*)_?(?<version>[0-9]+)?\.dwg" );`

Comment: ^^ Stack seems to of chosen an unfortunate place to split that comment :p, check there should be a space between the "," and "]"

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Linq query with `Enumerable.GroupBy` <strike>which should work</strike>(now tested):

```
var allFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDir, "*.dwg")
    .Select(path => new
    {
        Path = path,
        FileName = Path.GetFileName(path),
        FileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path),
        VersionStartIndex = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path).LastIndexOf('_')
    })
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.Path,
        x.FileName,
        IsVersionFile = x.VersionStartIndex != -1,
        Version = x.VersionStartIndex == -1 ? new Nullable<int>()
            : x.FileNameWithoutExtension.Substring(x.VersionStartIndex + 1).TryGetInt(),
        NameWithoutVersion = x.VersionStartIndex == -1 ? x.FileName
            : x.FileName.Substring(0, x.VersionStartIndex)
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Version)
    .GroupBy(x => x.NameWithoutVersion)
    .Select(g => g.First());

foreach (var file in allFiles)
{
    string oldPath = Path.Combine(sourceDir, file.FileName);
    string newPath;
    if (file.IsVersionFile && file.Version.HasValue)
        newPath = Path.Combine(versionPath, file.FileName);
    else
        newPath = Path.Combine(noVersionPath, file.FileName);
    File.Copy(oldPath, newPath, true);
}
```

Here's the extension method which i'm using to determine if a `string` is parsable to `int`:

```
public static int? TryGetInt(this string item)
{
    int i;
    bool success = int.TryParse(item, out i);
    return success ? (int?)i : (int?)null;
}
```

Note that i'm not using regex but string methods only.

Comment: Hi Tim, is Directory.EnumerateFiles only available in .NET 4.5?  I believe my current .NET version is v4.0.30319

Comment: Tim- I'm getting "System.IO.Directory does not contain a definition for EnumerateFiles" at Directory.EnumerateFiles. I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Comment: @DaBears: No, i'm also using .NET 4(it was new in 4). [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles(v=vs.100).aspx) doesn't need to load all into memory before it can start processing unlike  `Directory.GetFiles`,  similar to a `StreamReader`.

Comment: @DaBears: Are you sure that you're targetting .NET 4?

Comment: thats the last version I saw in my .NET folder.  Is there an easier way to determine exactly what I'm using?

Comment: @DaBears: You have to look at the compile-settings of your project, you can target it 2.0 even if 5.0 is installed. Right click over the project name in the solution explorer to get the Properties dialog.

Then select the Build tab.

Comment: @DaBears are you using Visual Studio? If you are, go to your projects properties and check the `Application` > `Target framework` to see what framework you are using

Comment: @TimSchmelter not under Build, but Application.

Comment: @Tim: good catch.  I've changed it from 3.5 to 4.0 saved and reopened.  Getting an error at .TryGetInt()  Thoughts?

Comment: @DaBears: `TryGetInt` is the extension method i'm using(look at the end of my answer). Just put it in  a public static class that is accessible. It's just the cleaner way of using `TryParse` in  a Linq query. @Some: I have not tested if your regex approach works. I'm just using a different non-regex approach that might be more efficient and is more readable(for people who are not so familiar with regular-expressions). However, if it works, it's indeed shorter.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
var files = new My.Computer().FileSystem.GetFiles(@"c:\to\the\sample\directory", Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.dwg");
foreach (String f in files) {
    Console.WriteLine(f);
};
```

***NB:*** Add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic` and use the following line at the beginning of the class:

```
using My = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices;
```

**UPDATE**

**The working sample[tested]:**

```
String dPath=@"C:\to\the\sample\directory";
var xfiles = new My.Computer().FileSystem.GetFiles(dPath, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.dwg").Where(c => Regex.IsMatch(c,@"\d{3,}\.dwg$"));
XElement filez = new XElement("filez");
foreach (String f in xfiles)
{
    var yfiles = new My.Computer().FileSystem.GetFiles(dPath, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, string.Format("{0}*.dwg",System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f))).Where(c => Regex.IsMatch(c, @"_\d+\.dwg$"));
    if (yfiles.Count() > 0)
    {
        filez.Add(new XElement("file", yfiles.Last()));            
    }
    else {
        filez.Add(new XElement("file", f));
    };
};
Console.Write(filez);
```

Comment: Really? Including Microsoft.VisualBasic in a C# project. It's already bad enough that it's there in Visual Basic apps, now let's not do that for C#.

Comment: @Snake What's wrong with `Microsoft.VisualBasic`? I bet if it were not named *VisualBasic* most .Net developers that make such statements like you did would think the opposite about it.

Comment: Why are you using `My.Computer().FileSystem.GetFiles` when the C# method `Directory.GetFiles` work exactly the same?

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this by string sort?  The only tricky part I see here is to convert the file name to a sortable format.  Just do a string replace from dd-mm-yyyy to yyyymmdd.  Then, sort the the list and get the last record out.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want considering fileList contain all file names

```
List<string> latestFiles=new List<string>();
foreach(var groups in fileList.GroupBy(x=>Regex.Replace(x,@"(_\d+\.dwg$|\.dwg$)","")))
    {
        latestFiles.Add(groups.OrderBy(s=>Regex.Match(s,@"\d+(?=\.dwg$)").Value==""?0:int.Parse(Regex.Match(s,@"\d+(?=\.dwg$)").Value)).Last());
    }
```

latestFiles has the list of all new files..

If fileList is bigger,use `Threading` or `PLinq`